# Python Script vs Cron Job

Tags: python, cron, archlinux

I need to run a **cron job** to generate a list of user rankings each week at exactly "00:00:00" UTC each Monday morning. Has anyone got an example for this, it's really doing my head in ... I looked into "crontab -e" and was instantly lost.

```
Basics:
 - Run the script, eg: /srv/django/get_rankings.py
 - Run the script at "00:00:00" and "00:05:00" every Monday.
 - Run the same script the next Monday ... and repeat
```

I'm on **Linux Arch**, any heads up would be amazing.

Thanks so much,
Hope all is well

Comment: It's **Arch Linux**, the best Linux distro.

Comment: Yeh, as soon as I wrote that I meant to update, but I had a pack of Fruit Tingles instead. Thanks Blender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

crontab put entry like,

```
00,05 0 * * 1 /srv/django/get_rankings.py
```

runs the script at 00.00 & 00.05 every Monday of every month

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

`*` in the value field above means all legal values as in braces for that column.
The value column can have a `*` or a list of elements separated by commas.

An element is either a number in the ranges shown above or two numbers in the range separated by a hyphen (meaning an inclusive range)

Comment: Thanks avasal, this is perfect and instantly makes sense. Great explanation ... I'll give it a crack.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -e`, and insert these:

```
0 0 * * 1 /srv/django/get_rankings.py
0 5 * * 1 /srv/django/get_rankings.py
```

`0 0` is midnight; `0 5` is 05:00am. `1` is Monday. The two stars mean "I don't care about the date". [Here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) is a good reference.

You can put it all in one line by saying "0 o'clock or 5 o'clock":

```
0,5 0 * * 1 /srv/django/get_rankings.py
```